# Local Docker RabbitMQ - Connection Timeout

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I'm working through an example in the Clojure Programming Cookbook that involves running RabbitMQ locally in Docker. I start it up using

`docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3`

and I see log output that includes the line

`started TCP listener on [::]:5672`.

When I try to connect to it using

`(langohr.core/connect {:host "172.17.0.2"})`

I get the error "Operation timed out (Connection timed out)". Not sure if it's relevant, but I'm on macOS 11.4.

Also,

`docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' some-rabbit`

returns

`172.17.0.2`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to map the ports:

```
 docker run -it --rm --name my-rabbitmq \
        -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

then you can connect using HTTP://localhost:15672  and in amqp with localhost:5672